# JTabbedPane - Cant remove individual tabs

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have a simple `JTabbedPane` that shows text files. Each tab contains a `JList` wrapped in a `JScrollPane` I would like to be able to close the individual tabs with a right click, but I can't get this seemingly simple behavior to work.

Here is what I've tried so far:

**Adding a listener to the Pane**

```
public class RightClickListener extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) { 
            remove(getComponentAt(e.getPoint()));
        }
    }
}
```

**Adding to the individual tabs**

```
public class RightClickListener extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) { 
            remove((Component) e.getSource());
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried several other variations, and nothing seems to work. Does anyone know why these components aren't being removed? I'd be happy to provide any additional details as necessary.

**UPDATE** More detail:

```
public void loadCode(String cFile, String cLine) {
    Scanner scan = null;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(new File(cFile));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace();}

    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    JList<String> list = new JList<String>(model);

    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        model.addElement(scan.nextLine());
    }

    JScrollPane newTab = new JScrollPane(list);
    tp.add(cFile, newTab);
    tp.addMouseListener(new RightClickListener());
}

public class RightClickListener extends MouseAdapter {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) { 
            remove(indexAtLocation(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you call `tabbedPane.addMouseListener(new RightClickListener());`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now in your listener, you're using `getComponentAt` - which will return the component at the point which was clicked (if you're clicking on the tab titles, you're going to get the JTabbedPane back).  Since the JTabbedPane was never added to itself, it can't remove that component...

Try using the `indexAtLocation` method instead - this will check if the x/y coordinates of the click correspond to a tab heading and return that tab's index (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html for more details)

```
public class RightClickListener extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
            tp.remove(tp.indexAtLocation(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like this is very close to what I need, but for some reason this removes every tab AFTER the current index is well. So if I remove tab 2, it deletes `3, 4, ... n` as well.

Comment: Hmmm... it doesn't behave that way in my demo.  Just to make sure, there aren't any other mouse listeners attached to either the JTabbedPane or it's components that are capable of deleting, are there?

Comment: This is a stretch, but you're only adding one MouseAdapter, correct?  If there were multiples, it would remove many tabs.   If you only have one MouseAdapter, you'll need to post more code (I'm flying blind as this solution works locally).  I suspect the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Oh god, I got it. I need to set that listener in the constructor. I load multiple text files, so it keeps adding listeners. Thanks so much.